# Concatenation of two hex-decimal addresses (PPN and VPO), forming a physical address

Tags: c, concatenation, virtual-memory, mmu

I'm reading about MMU translation and how a CPU can execute a load instruction that reads a byte at an address, leading to it concatenating the PPN from the PTE with the VPO from a virtual address, making a physical address. But I'm not sure how this concatenation is done. This is the paragraph I'm referring to:

[image]

> To begin, the MMU extracts the VPN ( OxOF) from the virtual address and
>   checks with the TLB to see if it has cached a copy of PTE OxOF from some previous
>   memory reference. The TLB extracts the TLB index (Ox03) and the TLB tag (Ox03)
>   from the VPN, hits on a valid match in the second entry of set Ox3, and returns
>   the cached PPN (OxOD) to the MMU.
>   If the TLB had missed, then the MMU would need to fetch the PTE from main
>   memory. However, in this case, we got lucky and had a TLB hit. The MMU now
>   has everything it needs to form the physical address. It does this by concatenating
>   the PPN (OxOD) from the PTE with the VPO (Ox14) from the virtual address, which
>   forms the physical address (Ox354).

But my question is, how are (0x14) and (0x0d) concatenated? Could someone possibly show me the steps to how this is done?

Comment: How is C involved in this?

Comment: The VPO seems to be only 6 bits, so by 0x14 they really mean b010100. So when you combine a PPN of 0x0D (b00001101) with it, you get b00001101010100, which is 0x354.

Comment: Do realize that the MMU is *only* hardware. It can do whatever it wants with the addresses (such as: split the address line in two parts, and treat these parts differently)

Comment: I suggest finding another source to learn from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's basically

```
(0xf << 6) | 0x14 // 0x3d4
```

So you take 6 bits from VPO and prepend it with bits from VPN.

Comment: His example was (0x0D << 6) | 0x14 = 0x354.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker I think it's OCR problems from the bad source: check the image and also the `O` (the letter `O`) in `OxOD`. Either way, as soon as "the formula" is known it's not a problem to substitute other operands.

Comment: I was reading the text--you're right, it doesn't match the image. But the math, oddly, still works.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker yep, it's either text and image were different initially, or just a funny coincidence :-)